# Several worker roles more expensive?

Tags: azure

What scenario is less expensive in $$$ using Windows Azure? And is it better to separate the two tasks. E-mails are rarely sent, but chat messages are posted all the time.

1. Having one worker role processing e-mails gotten from the Azure Queue every 10 seconds, and one worker role processing posted chat messages from the Azure every 1 second.
2. Having one generic worker role that processes both e-mails sending and chat messages every 1 second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Worker roles are most efficient when run at or near to full CPU capacity- you are, after all, paying by CPU hour for them. A useful way to achieve this is to combine worker roles such that all of your background jobs end up being performed in a single role.

A great way to run single worker role type architectures is to use some sort of generic worker role pattern- basically a plugin pattern whereby the worker role reads a message off the queue and uses some metadata encoded into the message (or the name of the queu) to determine the type of processing it requires. It will then go to blob storage to retrieve the .NET assembly to perform that type of processing, instantiate this into a new appdomain and marshall the context into that assembly for processing.

This is covered in the Asynchronous Workloads session in the [WIndows Azure Platform Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=413e88f8-5966-4a83-b309-53b7b77edf78&displaylang=en). This also contains a hands on lab that guides you through a sample implementation of one of these types of approaches.

The folks from Lokad have a really elegant implementation including all the polish and administration mechanisms that you'd need if you did this properly. Their implementation is New BSD licensed and was the winner of the MSFT Azure Partner of the YEar award last year. It's an essential part of almost every Azure project that I build. Highly recommended and trivial to integrate. http://code.google.com/p/lokad-cloud/

So in short, I prefer a generic worker role implemented as a plugin type pattern with dynamics type loading and instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

This all depends on your scaling strategy and how many instances you're going to need to run to handle your load.

If you're planning to take advantage of supported SLA (99.999 uptime) you will need at least 2 instances for every role.

Thus, if you split them up, you will need at least 4 instances.  If you keep them together, you'll need at least 2.

Processing 1 email per 10s and 1 chat message per second does not sound like a lot and I don't think you'll need more than 2 instances to handle everything.

However, if processing power gets to be lop-sided (i.e. chat messages need more computing power than email messages) and total load exceeds 4 instances, i suggest splitting them up, so that you can scale the two processes separately

Answer (score 0):

You're charged based on how many hours you're running and how many CPU cores you're running. So if you spin up four small VMs all doing the same thing versus two small VMs doing one thing and two doing another, the cost is the same.